# How to compute "take off" and "landing" time given a time series of altitudes?

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence of altitudes over time for an aircraft, how can I compute the specific time when the aircraft departs the ground (takes off) and returns to the ground for the final time (lands)?

Consider that an aircraft may depart an airport with a different altitude than the aircraft it lands at.

Also consider that the altitude during taxi may change slightly but should not be considered a take off.

[image]

**NOTE** An aircraft is likely to have "departed" the ground when its altitude has changed more than 1000 feet from it starting altitude.  The same would be true in reverse for a landing.

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: I don't possess the math background but my assumption would be to look for an average rate of change over a window of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, probably-good-enough idea: first, apply smoothing (e.g. Gaussian) to the data, then take the derivative. Call the first time point where the derivative differs significantly from zero the takeoff, and the last time point where the derivative differs significantly from zero the landing. Tweak the smoothing time constant and the threshold for "significantly different from zero" until you get good results with your data.

Comment: I agree with the approach ... any suggestions on where I can find a library that does the smoothing etc for me to look at and understand?  I'll need to do this in a Flutter/Dart application ... so I'm likely going to have to port from another language ... so any language example would be helpful @hobbs